# jdedwards enterprise 1: how to retrieve the field value?

Tags: jde, enterpriseone

I just started to do a development in JD Edwards Enterprise One.
I bump to seems simple things but I couldn't found how to do it, that is how to retrieve the value of the field (either after selecting from table or business view).

for e.g:
F0005.Select

now if I want to retrieve the value of DL01 and assign it to evt_myVar, what should I do?

note: What I am talking above is in creating the NER (Business Function)
Any info or hint to find the solution is really appreaciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have indexes of it, you can use the 'Fetch Single'.
When you use the 'Select', it always uses it with 'Fetch Next'.
You can retrieve and assign the value by Operation.